# A collection of ADTs with no duplicate constructors

Tags: haskell, dictionary, set

If I have a data type:

```
data Component = PositionC Double Double | HealthC Double | NameC String
```

- I want a collection of `Component`s
- I won't be storing any duplicates (ie: It won't have two HealthCs)
- I don't want to manually duplicate code

What technique, data structure, TemplateHaskell feature, etc, can I use to fulfil the above criteria?

I've experimented with Data.Set and Data.Map without success.

Data.Map attempt:

```
import Data.Map

data Component = PositionC Double Double | HealthC Double | NameC String

-- Unacceptable code duplication
data ComponentType = PositionCT | HealthCT | NameCT
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

type ComponentMap = Map ComponentType Component

foo :: ComponentMap
-- More annoying code duplication
foo = fromList [(HealthCT, HealthC 100), (NameCT, NameC "John")] 

fooHealth = foo ! HealthCT -- However, accessing works great
```

Data.Set attempt:

```
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

data Component = PositionC Double Double | HealthC Double | NameC String
    deriving Eq

foo :: Set Component
foo = Set.fromAscList [HealthC 100, NameC "John"] -- This works well

-- But accessing elements is very bad
fooHealth = Set.elemAt 0 $ Set.filter p foo
    where p (HealthC _) = True
          p _           = False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option is to use a record with optional fields:

```
data Component = Component 
                 { positionC :: Maybe (Double, Double)
                 ; healthC :: Maybe Double 
                 ; nameC :: Maybe String
                 }
```

Intuitively, access to fields will also be cheaper than using a `Set` or `Map`.

Setting a field

```
moveToOrigin c = c { positionC = Just (0,0) }
```

Getting a field

```
-- Requires health to be present
isDead c = fromJust (healthC c) == 0

-- If health is unknown returns False
saferIsDead c = health C == Just 0
```

Comment: Wow, here I was screwing around with complicated data structures, when the real solution was so simple. Thank you!